# D3 bar chart + gridlines = mouseover does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, bar-chart, gridlines

I have created a d3 bar chart with a mouseover event to present the total in that specific rectangle:

[image]

The group with the gridline is the first element I am creating in my svg:

```
  let svg = d3.select('#graph')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', svgW)
    .attr('height', svgH);
  let xGridLines = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat('');
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'grid')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left},${height + margins.top * 0.90})`)
    .call(xGridLines);
```

The problem starts if I want to move the grid to the front of the graph (I move the creation of the gridline after the chart creation). Then the mouseover stops working.

[image]

I tried to search for a solution but could not find any tutorial (I am also kinda newbie with d3).

Does anybody knows how to solve it? Here's my full code:

```
  let svg = d3.select('#graph')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', svgW)
    .attr('height', svgH);
  let xGridLines = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat('');
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'grid')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left},${height + margins.top * 0.90})`)
    .call(xGridLines);
  let chart = svg.append('g')
    .classed('display', true)
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margins.left},${margins.top})`);

  let series = chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'series');

  // Add labeled rects for each birthyear (so that no enter or exit is required).
  let serie = series.selectAll('.serie')
    .data(d3.range(0, objData.data.length))
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'serie');

  let xAxis = d3.axisTop(x);

  chart.append('g')
    .classed('x axis', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
    .call(xAxis);

  let tooltip = d3.select('#graph').append('div')
    .attr('class', 'indicators-graph__tooltip')
    .style('opacity', 0);

  let tooltipContainer = d3.select('.indicators-graph__tooltip').append('div')
    .attr('class', 'indicators-graph__tooltip__container');

  serie.selectAll('rect')
    .data((index) => {
      return [objData.data[index], objData.data[index]];
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', (d, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return d.first > 0 ? x(d.first) + 5 : 0;
      }
    })
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
      return y(d.key);
    })
    .attr('class', (d, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return 'indicators-graph__container__canvas__first-group';
      } else {
        return 'indicators-graph__container__canvas__second-group';
      }
    })
    .attr('width', (d, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        return x(d.first);
      } else {
        return d.first > 0 ? x(d.second) : x(d.second);
      }
    })
    .attr('height', function (d, i) {
      return lineHeight;
    })
    .text((d) => d.key)
    .on('mouseover', (d, i) => {
      let xAxis;
      let yAxis;
      let value;

      if (i === 0) {
        xAxis = (x(d.first) / 2) - 30;
        yAxis = y(d.key) + 15;
        value = d.first;
      } else {
        xAxis = x(d.first) + x(d.second / 2) - 30;
        yAxis = y(d.key) + 15;
        value = d.second;
      }

      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style('opacity', 0.9);

      tooltipContainer.html(value);

      tooltip.style('left', xAxis + 'px')
        .style('top', yAxis + 'px');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style('opacity', 0);
    });
```

Comment: In your gridlines group, add this: `attr("pointer-events", "none")`.